# ERB: add class to url_for with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multilingual

I'm creating a page with refinery which has multiple languages.
Now i want to add a language Switch and don't know how to do the followung:

```
<%= link_to 'DE', url_for( :locale => 'de' ), :class => "selected" %>
```

The selected should only be there if

```
I18n.locale == 'de'
```

I could do the following but that is a bit too much repetition and despite that it doesn't work, even tough i don't know why:

```
I18n.locale == 'de' ? link_to('DE', url_for( :locale => 'de' ), :class => "selected") : link_to('DE', url_for( :locale => 'de' ))
```

So how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'DE', url_for( :locale => 'de' ), :class => "#{ 'selected' if I18n.locale == 'de' }" %>
```

When it becomes more complex, abstract it.

Answer (score 0):

Haha thanks, your answer nearly worked, just had to convert it to a string because I18n.locale returns a symbol. That's why my (uggly) solution didn't work

```
<%= link_to 'DE', url_for( :locale => 'de' ), :class => "#{ 'selected' if I18n.locale.to_s == 'de' }" %>
```